# How to represent the efficency of a function in a plot

Tags: r, plot, time

In school, we are learning to use R and we had to find an algorithm to calculate the order of a permutation in different ways. So I came up with 4 different algorithms that can be compared. But now, I'd like to be able to display the time that each the function works depending on the size of the data that we give.

So first, I wanted to display the time given for at least one of the functions (I called it `calculOrdrePermutation`) without changing the size of the data.
So that's what I did :

```
createProcessTest <- function(func, variables, numberOfTests) {
  outputProgress <- T
  ptm <- proc.time()
  times <- c()
  for(i in 1:numberOfTests) {
    func(variables)
    times <- append(times, (proc.time() - ptm)[3])
    if(outputProgress & i %% 5 == 0) {
      print(paste((i/numberOfTests) * 100, "%"))
    }
  }
  return(times)
}

sampleSize <- 100
nbOperations <- 100
extrait <- sample(1:sampleSize, sampleSize)
matriceDePermutation <- trouverMatriceDePermutation(extrait)

tempsRapideMatrice = createProcessTest(calculOrdrePermutation, matriceDePermutation, nbOperations)
plot(y=tempsRapideMatrice, x=1:nbOperations, cex=0.1, type="l", main="Using matrix", sub="sans boucle", ylab="Time (s)", xlab="Number of iterations")
```

[image: Plot]
*It looks approximatively like this*

So that's not that bad, I'm able to display a plot that represent the time for this function. But it is linear, of course, so there's not much that interest us...

So I started to create a function that do the process by changing graduatly the `sampleSize` :

```
doFullTest <- function(func, useMatrix, numberOfTestsPerN, maxN) {
  temps <- c()
  for(sampleSize in seq(from=1, to=maxN, by=1)) {
    permut <- sample(1:sampleSize, sampleSize)
    
    if(useMatrix) {
      permut <- trouverMatriceDePermutation(extrait)
    }
    
    temps <- append(temps, mean(createProcessTest(func, permut, numberOfTestsPerN)))
  }
  return(temps)
}
```

And so I can use it this way :

```
plot(x=1:100, y=doFullTest(calculOrdrePermutation, T, 5, 100), type="h")
```

[image: histogram]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/wzbVqsH/Rplot02.png))</sub>

*Time used depending on the size of the data, from N=1 to N=100*

So what I asked is to run 5 times the function per size of data to take the mean, and then repeat with an increased size. But as you can see, it isn't possible to study it, I hoped to have a linear histogram (because my algorithm has a complexity of O(n) ).

Is there a problem in my code? Am I doing it totally wrong?

I'm pretty sure I'm not that far from my goal, but the result is quite upseting...

Thank you for your help!